# git svn dcommit with different user

Tags: git, git-svn, msysgit

I tried to perform `git svn dcommit` with different svn username using `--username` option, however it did not help. Commit was authored as default user (user which I used to clone svn repository).

Is it possible to perform `git svn dcommit` with specific svn user?

Comment: Is this only temporary, or do you want to change the user permanently?

Comment: or do you want username to correspond commit author?

Comment: @poke it is just temporary. There are several commits that should go to svn and I need all them to be committed with the specified svn username. I forgot to note I am using msysgit.

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko, yes this is svn author

Comment: According to git-svn code, dcommit doesn't accept --username option. Maybe if you patch it by adding "'username=s' => \$Git::SVN::Prompt::_username," it will work...

Answer (score 0):

I did it with running git "as another user":

1. I created a batch file with the command `git svn dcommit`
2. I saved the batch file in c:\
3. I pressed `Shift` + right-click on the batch file, "run as different user"
4. Give other user credentials
5. The commit is done with the "different user"